# How to display hidden input field value in django?

Tags: jquery, django

I am working on a small projects by using python, django and jquery.
At one place i have to show the value of integer field which is as hidden input.
The field will show only calculated value of other integer fields. 
How to do that ..please guide me...

Comment: Are you just trying to get the value of the <input type='hidden' value="someVal" id="someId" class="someClass"/> element?

Answer (score 0):

HiddenInput widget.

Read the manual...
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: I have gone through this manual. It describes about hidden input field by using widget. But how to display value in template without showing border of textbox of that field. The value won't come from database, it is calculated on the screen by using jquery.